# Why would multiple shared pointers pointing to the same memory cause memory leak?

Tags: c++

I am reading about shared pointers and the book say that it is bad idea having multiple shared pointers point to the same memory because if one shared_ptr reference count decrease to 0, it will deallocate that memory, making the other shared_ptr pointing to garbage.

```
int *z = new int;
shared_ptr<int> bad1(z); 
shared_ptr<int> bad2(z);
```

However, when the reference count for z becomes 0, wouldn't both shared_ptr know this?

Comment: Your book is correct. How would/could `bad1` or `bad2` "know about each other"? (They _do_, or more accurately they both share the same reference count, in the case where you copy-constructor copy-assign a `shared_ptr`, as in `shared_ptr<int> bad2 = bad1;`.)

Comment: It's a bit like selling something twice – after you've sold something once, it's no longer yours to sell, which is what you're attempting with `bad2`.

Comment: Looks like a double delete not a memory leak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That won't cause a leak. It's actually much worse, since you have two ***unrelated*** shared pointers pointing to the same memory. Which means both will think they have ownership of the memory, and each will try to free it on their own.

If you want two shared memory object pointing to the same memory, then use the `std::shared_ptr` initialization (or assignment):

```
shared_ptr<int> good1(new int);
shared_ptr<int> good2 = good1;
```

Comment: Well, "good" maybe.  Like all uses of shared pointers/ownership, it increases the risk of a leak.  Even mark-and-sweep language support results in "leaks" as obsolete unused objects have some incidental reference to them that will never be followed before application end.

Comment: @Some programmer dude wait if wouldn't good2 copy good1 so you still end up with two copies of shared_ptr?

Comment: @ManhNguyen No, that's what *shared* pointers do: They share a pointer to the same memory area.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you create two separate shared pointer objects, each holding the pointer z, and each with their own count. Therefore, bad1 would have a count of 1, as would bad2. The two shared pointer objects do not "know about one another", because they were constructed separately.

However, if you were to do something like this:

```
int *z = new int;
shared_ptr<int> bad1(z); 
shared_ptr<int> bad2 = bad1;
```

Then you end up invoking the copy constructor to construct bad2, and both shared pointers hold the same counter such that when one goes out of scope, it decrements the counter seen by the other shared pointer.