# C++ primer 5 edition: using get member to initialize another shared_ptr independent object

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

On C++ primer 5 edition. chapter 12. Dynamic memory.

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42)); // reference count is 1 
int *q = p.get(); // ok: but don't use q in any way that might delete its pointer

{ // new block
  // undefined: two independent shared_ptrs point to the same memory
    shared_ptr<int>(q);
} // block ends, q is destroyed, and the memory to which q points is freed
int foo = *p; // undefined; the memory to which p points was freed
```

> In this case, both p and q point to the same memory. Because they were created
>   independently from each other, each has a reference count of 1. When the block in
>   which q was defined ends, q is destroyed. Destroying q frees the memory to which q
>   points. That makes p into a dangling pointer, meaning that what happens when we
>   attempt to use p is undefined. Moreover, when p is destroyed, the pointer to that
>   memory will be deleted a second time.

As I see `q` is not a shared_ptr but a built-in pointer thus it doesn't has a reference count. Normally he should say the temporary shared_ptr object and `p` instead. isn't it?

- Also an I think this code wouldn't cause a Undefined Behavior! Because I've tried it and runs fine. Because as I guess an expression like:

  ```
  { // new block
    // undefined: two independent shared_ptrs point to the same memory
      shared_ptr<int>(q); // I think this will be removed by the compiler as an optimization.
  }
  ```

Thus I think there is only one shared_ptr manages that memory. So it is safe I think. But if he wrote:

```
{ // new block
  // undefined: two independent shared_ptrs point to the same memory
    shared_ptr<int> q2(q);
}
```

Then this is what he might mean.
Thank you!

Comment: *"Also an I think this code wouldn't cause a Undefined Behavior! Because I've tried it and runs fine."* I'm just going to warn you that that is a bad philosophy. The nature of undefined behavior is that appearing to work fine is something undefined behavior can do. The problem with undefined behavior is that it is not **guaranteed** to run fine.

Comment: Also, you might want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53232827/10957435). Not sure enough it's a duplicate to close it as such, but you might want to check that out.

Comment: @Chipster: Yes in fact I never do it  in real programs but I only wanted to know whether there are mistakes here in book or not?

Comment: Ah. I'm not sure if I'm qualified to answer your question. However, my linked question might answer yours.

Answer (score 1):

The presented code is indeed problematic and not showing what it was intended to show, but not because of some presumed compiler optimization...

The line:

```
shared_ptr<int>(q);
```

doesn't create a new temporary `shared_ptr` with q being a parameter sent to the constructor of the shared_ptr! **It creates a shared_ptr named *q***.

So it is indeed a bad code example and the fix that you propose is correct.

However as mentioned in the comments, the philosophy of: it runs thus it is not undefined behavior is wrong.

Another fix for the code in the example could be to use curly brackets {} for sending *q* as a parameter for the temporary `shared_ptr`:

```
int main() {
    shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42)); // reference count is 1 
    int *q = p.get(); // ok: but don't use q in any way that might delete its pointer
    
    { // new block
      // undefined: two independent shared_ptrs point to the same memory
        shared_ptr<int> {q}; // q is now a parameter to a temporary shared_ptr
    } // block ends, q is destroyed, and the memory to which q points is freed
    int foo = *p; // undefined; the memory to which p points was freed
}
```

One last note - the suggestion of giving a name to the shared_ptr inside the block doesn't really waive compiler optimization, as long as the actual object is not used the compiler may drop its creation. So if you want to make sure compiler optimization wouldn't happen you should go for:

```
int main() {
    shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42)); // reference count is 1 
    int *q = p.get(); // ok: but don't use q in any way that might delete its pointer
    
    { // new block
      // undefined: two independent shared_ptrs point to the same memory
        shared_ptr<int> ptr {q}; // q is now a parameter to a local shared_ptr
        *ptr = 42; // do something with ptr
    } // block ends, q is destroyed, and the memory to which q points is freed
    int foo = *p; // undefined; the memory to which p points was freed
    return foo; // do something with foo
}
```

Comment: "_as long as the actual object is not used the compiler may drop its creation_" What do you mean?

Comment: @curiousguy: The compiler removes that unsed statement as an optimization.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa What do you mean? A statement? You mean a variable definition? Unused? A statement has no "user".

Comment: @curiousguy: yes

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Compilers can't just "remove stuff". Unless "stuff" does nothing what so ever of course: an empty "wait loop" intended to be slow can be removed.

Comment: Your last point isn't quite correct. As per [as-if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule, if the code had *any* observable behaviour, the compiler would not just remove it. `delete`ing a passed pointer is most certainly observable behaviour.